# What does "printed upon a husk" mean?

Tags: meaning-in-context, phrase-meaning, sentence-meaning

In *THE SAINT* by *V.S. PRITCHETT*:

> The man is a saint, I thought. As saintly as any of those gold-leaf figures in the churches of
> Sicily. Golden, he sat in the punt. Golden, he sat for the next hour as I paddled him down the
> river. Golden and bored. Golden as we landed at the town and as we walked up the street back
> to my uncle's house. There he refused to change his clothes or to sit by a fire. He kept an eye
> on the time for his train back to London. By no word did he acknowledge the disasters or the
> beauties of the world. **If they were printed upon him, they were printed upon a husk**.

What does "printed upon a husk" mean here? Why would someone suddenly  print them(disasters and beauties I suppose) on him? I could understand its literal meaning but nothing more.

P.S. He(Mr. Timberlake) was very wet in the story if that matters.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

printed here is similar to *imprinted*. In other words, if the disasters or beauties of the world had an effect on him. We say: x was imprinted on someone's mind, for example.

on a husk or shell of a man. It suggests he has no substance, only an outside covering, like a corn hush or empty shell (an animal or plant).

Meaning: His interior self was destroyed or no longer existed.